# Divide $x=123456$ into three factors $x=uvw$ such that $uv^iw$ is divisible by 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, regular-language

I have the problem of dividing the string 123456 into three factors uvw that such $uv^iw$ as a number is divisible by three, where $\left|uv\right|\le4$ and $\left| v\right|>0$, i.e. the factors u and v should together only be 4 digits long.
I found the answer but just by simply trying out different values. My knowledge in number theory is very limited, I basically just know that a number is divisible by 3 if it contains three in its prime factorization... And I just cannot explain why it is that if I e.g. divide 123456  such that u=12, v=34, w=56 it's the case that for all small values of i, it's the case that $uv^iw$ is divisible by 3: $uv^2w=121156656, uv^3w=123930456, uv^4w=12133633656$ are all divisible by 3, why is that the case?

Comment: $123456 \ne 12\times 34 \times 56 = 22848$

Comment: The wording here is ambiguous.  By "dividing the string" do you mean contiguous substrings, $u+v+w$ = "123456"?  The exponent $i$ seems to imply multiplication, but then your examples seem to go back to an idea of concatenation.

Comment: It would be better to correct the wording (see edit link), if necessary, rather than to delete your Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't $v^i$ be repetition of $v$, not a power of the number $v$?  That seems more likely since we are talking about strings.  In that case $u=12,v=34,w=56$ is not correct.  The classic [divisibility rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) says that a number is a multiple of $3$ if and only if the sum of the digits is.  So as long as the sum of the digits in your string is a multiple of $3$, the whole number is.  If the sum of the digits in $v$ is a multiple of $3$, repeating it will not change the status of the number.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm sorry, I have mixed that up, probably because of the divisibility condition. Should I delete the question?

Comment: In the example $v$ = "34" and $v^i = 34^i$ is converted back to a string, what makes it work is that $34 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, and thus any power of $v$ will again be congruent to 1 mod 3.

Comment: @hardmath:  that is correct, but I stand by the claim that repeating strings is what is intended in this problem.

Comment: I see that the OP did some calculations and asks about why those worked out, so my remark was aimed at those, not intended as a criticism of the string repetition interpretation (note my Comments asking the OP to clarify or correct wording of the Q).